# Generate a rectangular box

Tags: perl, pdf

I am using Perl to generate a PDF file with the module
[`PDF::API2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2).
I want to draw rectangular boxes, each of which should contain a set of data based on a hash. I am displaying data using the following method, which is displayed in tabular format.

```
my $pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "mydata.pdf");
my $page = $pdf->page;
.............
.............
my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;

$pdftable->table(
     $pdf,
     $page,
     \@tbl,
     x             => 50,
     w             => 400,
     start_y       => 630,
     start_h       => 630,
     next_y        => 630,
     next_h        => 630,
     padding       => 5,
     padding_right => 10,
);
```

where `@tbl` contains the data as an array of hashes.

The rectangular boxes should be drawn based on the hash keys. If I have N keys, then N boxes should be drawn with their values.

How can I draw boxes in PDF using Perl? I am unable to find any functions in `PDF::API2`.

Here is an example diagram of how it should appear:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See
[`PDF::API2::Content`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2::Content)
for *Methods for adding graphics*

In particular, the section *Path Construction* describes the `rect` method which will draw one or more rectangles

Comment: Yes, I can see the `rect` methods. 
`$content->rect($x1, $y1, $w1, $h1, ..., $xn, $yn, $wn, $hn)` and 
`$content->rectxy($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);`

I am feeling difficulty in understanding the arguments. Can you please explain it ?

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to the `PDF::Table` object constructor, in your example `\@tbl`, is where you put the text to be written to the table. It is **not** an array of hashes as you you state. It's an array of arrays.

To be more precise, it's an array reference. Each element is another array ref, which represents each row of the table. The elements of each nested array will be the cells of that row.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::Table;    

my $pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "mydata.pdf");
my $page = $pdf->page;
my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;

my @tbl = (
    ["1\tNAME:ABC\n\tGRADE:4"],
    ["2\tNAME:XYZ\n\tGRADE:5"],
);

$pdftable->table(
     $pdf,
     $page,
     \@tbl,
     x             => 50,
     w             => 400,
     start_y       => 630,
     start_h       => 630,
     next_y        => 630,
     next_h        => 630,
     padding       => 5,
     padding_right => 10,
);

$pdf->saveas('mydata.pdf');
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question asked. It should be a comment on the question.

Comment: I beleive it is, OP is using `PDF::Table` (although they neglected to `use PDF::Table` in their example code). this is how you put data in a `PDF::Table` object

Comment: Are you saying that your code will generate a rectangular box as described? If you are certain that the OP is using a module that they haven't mentioned then you should at least mention the fact in your answer, and probably edit the question as well.

Comment: Please add e.g. `@Borodin` to comments so that their recipients receive notification that they have a message waiting.

Comment: It would help readability a lot if you would capitalise your English correctly and use the markup consistently.

Comment: @Borodin I am certain they are using the module. if you look again, you'll see it is in fact in their code.

Comment: As I said, *"If you are certain that the OP is using a module that they haven't mentioned then you should at least mention the fact in your answer, and probably edit the question as well"*. Answers that don't state such significant assumptions are all but useless. Please keep *Stack Overflow* correct, clean, and useful.

Comment: And will your solution generate a rectangular box as described?

Comment: I suggest that you create exemplary data and code and show the output. *Then* this page will be useful to others who arrive here from Google or similar